# Context binding in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I broadcast an event `langChange` to accomplish localization.
The problem here is find an elegant way to call `this.loadContent()` on entering on the page this controller is attached AND when `langChange` is fired too.
That `bind(this)` doesn't doing what I want I guess.

I would avoid the `this` alias solution like `var $this=this; [...]`.

```
app.controller('ctrl', ["$scope","Service",
    function($scope,Service){
        this.loadContent = (function(){
                Service
                    .getSection()
                    .then(function (res) {
                        $scope.content = res.data.template;
                    });
        }());
        $scope.$on('langChange', (function(){
            this.loadContent();
        }).bind(this));
}]);
```

**EDIT:** Based on @Petr Averyanov answer I tried the below solution but `loadContent` isn't even called when `langChange` is fired.

```
app.controller('ctrl', ["$scope","Service",
    function($scope,Service){
        console.log("loading content..")
        var _this = this;
        _this.loadContent = function(){
                console.log("load")
                tutorialService
                    .getSection()
                    .then(function (res) {
                        $scope.content = res.data.template;
                    });
        }();
        $scope.$on('langChange', _this.loadContent);
}]);
```

I tried also the one commented in his post, I get `_this.loadContent is not a function` I guess there are still context issues...

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
app.controller('ctrl', ["$scope","Service",
    function($scope,Service){
        var vm = this;
        vm.loadContent = function(){
                Service
                    .getSection()
                    .then(function (res) {
                        $scope.content = res.data.template;
                    });
        }();
        $scope.$on('langChange', vm.loadContent);
        /* or
           function() {
             vm.loadContent();
           }
        */
}]);
```

Comment: I know about the `this` alias solution. I would avoid this solution if possible.

Comment: @alfredopacino if you know about a possible solution but choose not to use that solution, then your question should be more like "I am looking for a different way to solve this than...." to avoid this kind of confusion, both for answerers and others who might have a similar problem but not know about the avoided solution.